# CPQ: Generate Quote Documents for more than 25 Quotes

Tags: apex, api, cpq, bulk, schedule

I'm trying to generate Quote Documents for several Quotes simultaneously. We're using a schedule but calling the API and running up against a limit: we can only call the API to create Quote Documents for 25 Quotes at a time.

Is there something like a bulk operation that exists for creating quote documents via the API?

Comment: Do you have an example of an error message that you're receiving if you cross the 25 quote threshold? I don't see mention of 25 being a hard limit in the current CPQ documentation.

Comment: is this the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_generate_proposal.htm) you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting [this limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) (concurrent API requests lasting 20+ seconds) = 25

> Here are the allocations for various types of orgs for concurrent requests (calls) with a duration of 20 seconds or longer:
>
> `Org Type                          Limit`
>
> `Developer Edition and Trial orgs`   `5`
>
> `Production orgs and Sandbox`       `25`

Working around this basically means either reducing the complexity of the quoute itself or self-limiting your API requests